# Access pipe results in controller or template

Tags: angular

I have a search pipe which filters a list of objects.  I then want to perform an action on all objects that matched that filter.  I realize I can import the pipe in my component and rerun the filter but is there any way to access the filtered results themselves?

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchText"/>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of items | mySearch:searchText">{{item.name}}</li>
</ul>
<button (click)="doActionOnMatchingItems(???)">Do Action</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Try</strike>

```
*ngFor="let item of filteredItem = (items | mySearch:searchText)"
```

And then use `filteredItem` wherever you want

---

Unlike Angular 1 I'd be happy to aliasing filter result like below. The same has been supported in Angular since version 4. Check `NgForOf` docs [here](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf)

```
*ngFor="let item of items | mySearch:searchText as filteredItem"
```

Comment: This looks like a good solution at first glance. But don't forget, this runs more than once, undoing the result of `doActionOnMatchingItems(???)`.

Comment: @rinukkusu Good point, but `items | mySearch:searchText` is also going to evaluate on each tick. Just I added new variable assignment. I'd prefer to add `trackBy` in such case so improve performance :) Thanks for heads up brother, Cheers ;)

Comment: @PankajParkar, I just started with Angular2 and I found a possible solution here in this post. However I'm getting the following error: *"Bindings cannot contain assignments"* using your solution above. My `HTML` contains this: (`*ngFor="let item of filteredItems = (items | CustomPipe: [param1, param2, param3]); let first = first">`). By the way, is it a new feature? I'm asking because i'm still using Angular 2 RC 4. Regards :)

Comment: Oh sorry, this isn't working,  I just added an answer, I thought this would have work. Will check om GitHub for this

Comment: Great news! @developer033 this is supported in [Angular 4.2 now](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf)

Comment: @PankajParkar oh yes.. in fact, the `as` *syntax* is possible since Angular 4.0.0 :)

Comment: @developer033 wasn't sure, thanks for precise information :)