# Get length of array in ngFor after pipes transformation

Tags: angular, angular2-pipe

I have the following template:

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of myArray | customPipe1 | customPipe2; let l = length">
  Here is the length of my ngFor : {{l}}
</div>
```

Unfortunately length doesn't exist in ngFor. How can I work around this issue to have the length available inside my ngFor?

Comment: You already have `myArray.length` I don't understand the issue

Comment: It depends what you want it for, could you give more context? You can see what's available from `ngFor` in the docs: https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf

Comment: @echonax the length can change by the use of pipes. For instance a filter function :)

Comment: @PierreDuc ah thanks, that might be a case.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Another solution could be the following

```ts
<div *ngFor="let item of myArray | customPipe1 | customPipe2; let l = count">
  Here is the length of my ngFor : {{l}}
</div>
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/jWD9oVtA3CQM6QdcfFVS?p=preview)**

See also

- https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/directives/ng_for_of.ts#L15-L17

Comment: Nice catch :D https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/directives/ng_for_of.ts#L21

Comment: @echonax Yes, that is:) https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/directives/ng_for_of.ts#L17

Comment: How can we write count of the loop?

Answer (score 16):

```ts
<div *ngFor="let item of myArray | customPipe1 | customPipe2 as result">
  Here is the length of my ngFor : {{result.length}}
</div>
```

See also https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf

Comment: Since final Angular 2 version launched, I was expecting this to work and had added answer long back :D [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39476552/2435473), +1 for link

Comment: how can I get the length outside of the ngFor?

Comment: @Luckylooke `{{(myArray | customPipe)?.length}}`

Comment: Thanks @GünterZöchbauer, but I was wondering about solution without need of multiple execution of the pipe. Something like:
```<div *ngFor="let item of myArray | heavySearchExecution as result">
  Here is the length of my ngFor : {{result.length}}
</div>
<div *ngIf="!result.length">
  No results, please do something else...
</div>```

Comment: Do the filtering in code and assign the resulting array to a field and use this field in bindings instead.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is not well documented in the Angular doc, you can find under source code of Angular at -

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/directives/ng_for_of.ts

*ngFor accepts count params.

```
constructor(public $implicit: T, public ngForOf: NgIterable<T>, public index: number,public count: number) {
}
```

So we can get the count like -

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items | pipe; let l = count">
<div>{{count}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Günter Zöchbauer  `{{(myArray | customPipe)?.length}}` - Working as Expected

Answer (score 0):

This might sound dirty (it is)

But `const count = document.getElementbyId('id-of-wrapper').childElementCount;` will do the trick.

Need to call this function when some thing changes.

Pros

- Not require re calculation of pipe
- Works
- count available outside of loop

Cons

- dirty (a bit)
- not proper angular way
- dependency on dom